# WinHTTPRequest : ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vbscript, winhttprequest

I am getting error - 800A01AD while executing the following vbs code.

`strURL = "http://maps.yahoo.com/maps_result.php?q1=newyork"`
`Set myRequest = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTPPRequest.5.1")`
`myRequest.Open "GET", strURL`
`myRequest.Send`
`msgbox myRequest.ResponseText`

It throws 'ActiveX component can't create object'. I have WinHTTP.dll registered on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a genuine copy/paste then you have a typo in CreateObject("WinHTTP.`WinHTPPRequest`.5.1")

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try with **MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP** and tell me if it works for you or not ?

```
On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://maps.yahoo.com/maps_result.php?q1=newyork", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "test.txt", 2
```